# Changing Bundle ID of iOS app before submitting binary

Tags: ios, iphone, cfbundleidentifier

I would like to change the bundle ID of my app on itunes connect.  I have not uploaded yet a binary, however I already have enabled game center (created 2 leaderboards and 2 achievements) and in-app purchasing (created 2 in-apps).  I don't see anywhere the ability to change my app information of bundle id.  Can I change my bundle ID now or I can't?  If I can, please let me know how.

Comment: You can not change your bundle id for an application once you create it in iTunes Connect. To accomplish what you are asking would require creating a new bundle id in the dev portal and then creating a new app in iTunes Connect with that new bundle id and recreating your leader boards, iap's, etc. Why exactly do you want to change it?

Comment: I want to change the bundle id to accurately reflect a new app name.  Actually what I would like to do is change the app id and the bundle id associated with this app.  Apple says I can change the associated bundle id in itunesconnect by selecting More Info/About this App, on the app web page, but it just displays the bundle id, doesn't allow me to change it.

Comment: Without uploading a binary I may have disqualified changing bundle id because I turned on game center.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To change your bundle ID (while app is still in the prepare for submission status), delete your leaderboards. Go back to "my apps" and the drop down menu will appear for you to select a new bundle ID, or create a new bundle ID.

After that, you can recreate your leaderboards again.